# pthread wait() takes way longer than expected when the main window is hidden

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, pthreads

We are having an issue when waiting in a thread on MacOS and the main window is hidden, the wait function takes up to 10 seconds even if we request it to wait 100ms.

The main program is running on a Cocoa window, and an other thread is running permanently, waiting 100ms every iteration.
Everything works fine when the main window is visible, but once the window is hidden, the problem starts happening after some time, i.e. the wait starts waiting for several seconds. We suspect the system to stop waking up the application as often because it's not visible anymore.

We are using pthread_con_wait, but the same problem happens using usleep or boost::sleep (which are probably using the same underneath).

Is there a way to prevent this or a flag to set to tell the system we are still running and we want to be woken up?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's OS v10.9 or later, your app could be napping away:
[Power Efficiency Guide for Mac Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/power_efficiency_guidelines_osx/AppNap/AppNap.html)

Document says, it can be prevented with [`NSProcessInfo`](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSProcessInfo_Class/index.html) class.

> ### Managing Activities
>
> The system has heuristics to improve battery life, performance, and
>   responsiveness of applications for the benefit of the user. You can
>   use the following methods to manage activities that give hints to the
>   system that your application has special requirements:
>
> ```
> beginActivityWithOptions:reason:
>
> endActivity:
>
> performActivityWithOptions:reason:usingBlock:
> ```
>
> In response to creating an activity, the system will disable some or
>   all of the heuristics so your application can finish quickly while
>   still providing responsive behavior if the user needs it.
>
> ...
>
> ```
> id activity = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] ?  
> beginActivityWithOptions:NSActivityLatencyCritical  
>                   reason:@"Good Reason"];  
> // Perform some work.  
> [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] endActivity:activity];
> ```

Note,

> `NSActivityLatencyCritical`
>
> Flag to indicate the activity requires the highest amount of timer and I/O precision available.
>
> **IMPORTANT** Very few applications should need to use this constant.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly the problem.